# Fatal error: Cannot declare class error, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\MI_CARPETAWEB\controllers\error.php on line 3

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class error, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\MI_CARPETAWEB\controllers\error.php on line 3

Me da ese error y me muestra que en class error extends Constroller{ esta el error en esa linea 
use el modo _once pero no soluciona ayuda..

```
<?php

class error extends Controller{

    function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct();


    }
    function index(){
        $this->view->render('error', '404');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Probaste agregando un nombre de espacio? `namespace miProyecto;` y, para acceder a la clase `$objeto = new miProyecto\error();` Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php